Why does calcium homeostasis require more physiology than other electrolytes?
I've been learning about regulation of serum electrolyte concentration. From what I've seen, serum potassium, sodium, H^+ and carbonate levels are managed by aldosterone and angiotensin II. If I've understood correctly it seems that this hormonal feedback system is pretty much all managed from within the kidney itself, reading levels and releasing hormones to control reabsorption/secretion in the nephrons.
Calcium and phosphate homeostasis seems to be quite a bit more complex, with the whole parathyroid gland and part of the function of the thyroid gland dedicated to this via PTH and calcitonin, and also vitamin D. I'm not sure I've fully understood why calcium and phosphate homeostasis needs so much additional complexity compared with sodium and potassium. Maybe this is partly because calcium and phosphate homeostasis involves talking to the bones, but this is not necessary for other electrolytes? Is there another reason?
There are also other important electrolytes such as magnesium, chloride, and sulphate. I haven't seen anything much about how serum levels for these electrolytes are managed. Are there hormonal feedback mechanisms for these electrolytes also?

I'm curious as to why you think hormonal regulation via the parathyroid gland is more complex than hormonal regulation via the adrenal glands (renin splits a liver protein, angiotensin I, a piece of which is split by angiotensin converting enzyme in your lungs and kidneys into angiotensin II. which causes blood vessels to constrict and stimulates the pituitary gland to secrete antidiuretic hormone, which... (etc.) That's not simple to  me. Basically both are hormones released into the blood. As to the others, what were your search terms?

@anongoodnurse well the parathyroid appears to be a whole organ dedicated to calcium homeostasis. The renin angiotensin aldosterone system is also complex, but using some functionality of other organs seems less complex to me than needing a complete new organ. Also it's clear to me how PTH and calcitonin can regulate Ca^2+ within a range, but I didn't see how Na^+ concentration can be decreased, only increased eg. via aldosterone. The question was more about comparison to Mg, SO$_4$ and Cl though.

I don't agree with you about degrees of complexity and "complete new organ(s)", but re. decreasing Na concentration, that's what antidiuretic hormone is for, which is secreted by the pituitary gland (is that a complete new organ?). if your question is about the other ions, evidence of a search is pretty much a requirement on this site. As a common ion, Mg, like other ions, is pretty tightly controlled and a brief search should get you some results.

I would argue that sodium, potassium (and H+) regulation is much more complex than calcium (and phosphate) - for the following reasons:

sodium, potassium (and H+) are not just regulated in their own right, their regulation is intertwined with one another, and also affects blood pressure, vascular resistance and plasma osmolality, NOTE: (rough) calculated osmolarity = 2 (Na+) + 2 (K+) + Glucose + Urea
there are arguably more organs involved, and more hormones/chemicals

However, I admit that hormones of calcium homeostasis tend to have multiple functions at different sites (whereas the key players in sodium/potassium regulation broadly tend to do one thing)
FOR REFERENCE:
Renin-angiotensin- aldosterone system (RAAS) includes the following elements:

liver (angiotensinogen) - precursor
lungs (ACE) - enzyme for conversion (AT1>AT2)
kidney (renin) - low renal perfusion > more renin release
adrenal gland (aldosterone) - produced in response to antiotensin II and renin, causes reabsorption of sodium and excretion of potassium

In addition to this, there is:

hypothalamus/posterior pituitary (vasopressin/ADH) - increases water and sodium reabsorption
heart (ANP) - dilate afferent arteriole, inhibit sodium and water reabsorption

Sensor mechanisms:

kidney - afferent arteriole - senses the incoming blood pressure to the glomeruli
hypothalamus - osmoreceptors - sense osmolality and, if low, induce release of vasopressin/ADH
carotid sinus - baroreceptors - sense blood pressure and cause vasoconstriction
heart (as above)

Sources:

Na: gut absorption. Mainly extracellular.
K: gut absorption, release from lysed cells. Mainly intracellular

From a clinical standpoint, there are plenty of reasons why sodium/potassium regulation is important:

hypertension - modern antihypertensives directly act on the above systems (e.g. ACE-inhibitors, diuretics)
hypotension - probably most significant in critical care settings (vasopressors...)
hyponatraemia - can be a life-threatening condition, diagnosing and treating it requires assessment of fluid status (i.e. hypovolaemic / euvolaemic / hypervolaemic), although this does not usually involve targeting the homeostatic systems (the exception would be SIADH)
hypernatraemia - usually due to insufficient water intake or excessive losses
hyperkalaemia - can also be life-threatening (heart is very sensitive to electrolyte imbalance, and particularly to potassium), most often is a result of renal impairment or excessive potassium release (e.g. burns, rhabdomyolysis)
From the list above, it becomes aparent that these systems are at the core of most physiological stresses and many disease states. The challenge is that manipulating one element (e.g. sodium level) can have knock-on effect on other characteristics (e.g. blood pressure).

Calcium

parathyroid - parathyroid hormone - released due to low Ca:

increases renal Ca reabsorption (decreases PO4 reabsorption)
stimulates kidneys to activate vitamin D (calcifediol to calcitriol)
releases calcium from the bone (via osteoclasts)


vitamin D - causes more calcium absorption from the gut
thyroid - calcitonin - released due to high Ca;

stimulates calcium deposition in the bone (via osteoblasts),
inhibits renal calcium reabsorption,
inhibits calcium absorption from the gut



Clinically, these are the typical scenarios for disregulated calcium

hypercalcaemia - hyperparathyroidism, malignancy
hypocalcaemia - hypoparathyroidism (e.g. after thyroid surgery), insufficient (calcium/vit D) intake

In general, for understanding any electrolyte regulation, the key questions are:

what are the sources?
where is it located (intra/extracellular)?
what are the reservoirs (if any)?
how is it removed from the body?

For reference, this is an (incredibly detailed) review of calcium (and phosphate) regulation:
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279023/

Thank you, this was really interesting. Part of my question is still open though, which is about how these two mechanisms compare to magnesium, chloride and sulphate regulation. I've spent a while looking and have not been able to pin down an understanding of how Mg levels are regulated, even though I know they have to be tightly controlled and hypo or hyper magneseamia are both critical.
